# nginx proxy without changing port

Tags: nginx

I'm running an nginx proxy server to enable web access to multiple servers on my network on the same port (443). One of the servers (of urls) has the habit of redirecting to another port and since this port is not open on my firewall fail to connect. I was hoping to have nginx deny that redirect. So far I have the following which works, but ads port 8443 the url which is my next goal to remove:

With the following the client is redirected from 443 to 4040:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl http2;
    server_name host_name;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://internal_ip:4040/;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        send_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

When I enter the url of the server, I'm redirected to url:4040 which then errors (404).

The following does work, but ads the server port (8443) to the url:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl http2;
    server_name hostname;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://internal_ip:4040/;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        send_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

When I enter the url of the server, I'm redirected to url:8443 and the internal server is shown. Is it possible to NOT add 8443 and simply go to internal ip without changing or adding ports? What also could help if I'm first redirected to /admin because the first settings work when simply entering url/admin in my browser, it then skips redirecting to 4040.

Hope my problem is clear and what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Is the server generating a 3xx redirect? You could test it using `curl -I` and observing the value of the `Location` response header. But the redirection is probably originating from the service at `https://internal_ip:4040`, rather than the reverse proxy.

Comment: Yes I'm guessing that to, so there is not way of not redirecting on the remote side during proxy? I have checked, I'm not able to change things on the remote side.

Comment: Nginx can modify the `Location` response header using `proxy_redirect` or modify the body of a response using `sub_filter`. I cannot see how 8443 can leak out using the configurations in your question. So you need to do a lot of testing using `curl -I` to identify the corrective action required.